# Code gives NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have made five classes (as shown below). When I run my code it gives me "NullPointerException"

First class

```
public class PasPosition {

      boolean lessThanThirty;
      boolean ThirtyToFifty;
      boolean FiftyToHundred;

     public PasPosition(boolean value1, boolean value2, boolean value3)
     {
        lessThanThirty = value1;
        ThirtyToFifty = value2;
        FiftyToHundred = value3;

    }

}
```

Second Class

```
  public class CssPosition {

    boolean lessThanThirty;
    boolean ThirtyToFifty;
    boolean FiftyToHundred;
    public CssPosition(boolean value1,boolean value2, boolean value3)
    {
        lessThanThirty = value1;
        ThirtyToFifty = value2;
        FiftyToHundred = value3;
   }
 }
```

Third class

```
  public class SiteData {

     PasPosition pas;
     CssPosition css;


  }
```

last class

```
  public class Test {

    SiteData[] sitedata = new SiteData[2];

    public void test()
    {

        for(int i=0;i<sitedata.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(sitedata[i].css.FiftyToHundred);
            System.out.println(sitedata[i].css.ThirtyToFifty);
            System.out.println(sitedata[i].css.lessThanThirty);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: When does `css` or `pas` get initialised?

Comment: Please paste the *error message* of the NullPointerException.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication16.Test.test(Test.java:21)
        at javaapplication16.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: You have declare array of SiteData but not initialize that's why you are getting NullPointerException.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you didn't init the objects.

You must know that in java, an object in a class will not be automatically inited. You must use `new` operator.

```
public class SiteData {
    PasPosition pas=new PasPosition(false,false,false); 
    CssPosition css=new CssPosition(false,false,false);//use your own initial value
}
```

Comment: Its is still giving me the same error. Following is the error  : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication16.Test.test(Test.java:21)
        at javaapplication16.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @Bakhtawar Please give the full Main.javaor I will not know where line 25 is.

Comment: I figured out the problem...Thanks though...after reading one of the comments above I realized I have declared the array but not initialized it.